# Webstorm file switcher bug workaround

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Anyone knows a workaround for the file switcher bug in Webstorm?

It's that abominable bug that happens if you accidentally press and release ctrl+tab quickly to switch to previous file and then loose all keyboard input until you restart Webstorm....

Apparently Webstorm opens the file switch dialog but since it closes very quickly in this case it 'forgets' to release keyboard focus.... the closed dialog keeps the focus and you cannot regain it.

Happens to me every 20 minutes or so when I forget to slow myself down when switching files.... Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: I have never experienced anything like that myself -- Switcher always works fine for me regardless of the speed. Maybe it's specific to your OS / setup? I'm on Windows 7. Anything interesting in logs (Help | Show Log in...) ?

Comment: Happens to me at the office with Win7 and at home on Ubuntu... so I don't think it's an OS thingy... The logs don't show anything. I noticed that when you try to recreate the bug it happens after about a minute of quickly switching between files.... so it may be elusive to capture... maybe it also has to do with overall CPU usage... happened more when I was switching between Apps and then between files in WS.

Comment: TBH: I have no clue how I can help with debugging this behaviour. It this is very persistent in your case and bothers you ... I may only suggest to submit a ticket to the [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) and see what devs may suggest about it (they may have seen similar tickets or what not)...